# How to pause a FOR loop in Javascript in a function?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

There's a query per second limit in Google Places API, so I need to slow down my loop which sends requests:

```
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
      for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
    RequestInfo(result);
  }
}
```

Any idea how I can do that? I'm a bit of a newb.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738732/delay-sleep-in-javascript

Comment: @Gloria not quite. Similar question but different intended result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive solution,

```
function requestInfoWrapper(results, i) {
    i = i + 1;
    if (i >= results.length) {return};
    requestInfo(results[i]);
    setTimeout(function() {requestInfoWrapper(results, i);}, 1000);
}
```

Some example code to test it,

```
   var results = ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3"];
   function requestInfo(str) {console.log(str);}
   requestInfoWrapper(results, -1);
```

Also integrated with your code would just be,

```
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
    }

    requestInfoWrapper(results, -1);
}
```

Comment: @CrazyTrain: though that only works if `results` is global scope, and as long as `callback` isn't called before the last `setTimeout` occurs. ;-)

Comment: Ok, but would the requestInfoWrapper function have access to the results array? Sorry I'm a bit of a newb.
*edit* The results isn't global scope

Comment: @BradChristie: Yeah, I was commenting on  the initial solution, which I assumed would have been placed inside the `callback` function. The last solution should modify `requestInfoWrapper` to pass in the `results` array.

Comment: Edited so results doesn't have to be global.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++){
    (function(result){
        setTimeout(function(){
            RequestInfo(result);
        }, 1e3 * i);
    })(result);
}
```

You can use `setTimeout` and space them out to execute every `1 second * n` (where `n` is the current iteration number).

And, for the more to the point answer, JavaScript doesn't have a "sleep" method (nor would you want it to; it's single threaded and would tie up anything else while it waited).

Comment: You've got the "callback in a loop" problem.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: admittedly I'm not familiar enough to maps api, nor do I know _exactly_ what `callback` is; I'm assuming you mean callback fires a bunch of `RequestInfo`'s which in turn recalls callback (lather, rinse, repeat)?

Comment: Nothing specific to an api. It's just that the callback you're passing to `setTimeout` references the `result` variable, which is scoped to the enclosing function. Because the variable is overwritten in each iteration of the loop, when the callbacks are finally invoked, they'll be referencing the last value to which `result` was set, which will be `undefined`.

Comment: Hrm, that's not working for me. What's the 1e3 bit about? Should I change that to something else?

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Oh, duh. Heh, not thinking today. Should be fixed. ;-) **user**: 1e3 is just notation for 1 second (I find it easier than 1000). Case in point: 1/2 second = 0.5e3 (over 500), 1/4 = 0.25e3 (over 2500), etc.

Comment: @user2721465: `1e3` is just a somewhat annoying way to spell `1000.0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout to call the function recursively.

```
var i = 0;
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
  setTimeout(function() { 
    i++; 
    if (i < results.length) { 
      RequestInfo(results[i]);
      callback(results, status);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I assume you're intending a recursive call somewhere?