# Can I pause for cycle 500mil sec in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

I have this function to move an object and I want to set an interval of 500 mil secs on my cycle. No jQuery, just javascript. I have try setInterval('',500)

```
function shot() {
    document.getElementById('power').play();
    for (var i=140; i<400; i++)
    {  
        document.getElementById('shot').style.visibility='visible';
        imgShot.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) - 130 + 'px';  
        imgShot.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) - i + 'px';
        setInterval('',500);
    }           
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `setInterval('',500);` to do?  Do you want to wait 500ms after each iteration in the `for` loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497092/how-to-pause-a-for-loop-in-javascript-in-a-function

Comment: I think you want `setTimeout` and increment each iteration by the step. `setTimeout(func, i*500)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to block sequential execution in JavaScript is to create a busy loop (or use a blocking function like `alert`): but you do not want to do this as it will *freeze the user interface* - including updating the UI display of the elements movement!

Instead, structure the code such that it uses *asynchronous callbacks* - this model allows the browser event loop to continue uninterrupted so that it can react to user input and update the display from the DOM changes.

```
document.getElementById('power').play();
document.getElementById('shot').style.visibility='visible';

var i = 140;
function moveIt() {
    imgShot.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) - 130 + 'px';  
    imgShot.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) - i + 'px';
    i++;
    if (i < 400) {
      // If have more, schedule again in .5s
      // Remember that setTimeout *returns immediately* because it
      // is an asynchronous operation.
      setTimeout(moveIt, 500);
    } else {
      // This will be executed when animation finishes.
    }
}

moveIt();
// This will be executed after first movement which is well before
// the animation finishes. We could also use setTimeout(moveIt, ..) here,
// depending on what is desired.
```

Or, better, use something like [`jQuery.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) which takes care of much of the repetitive stuff. (You may have to write a custom easing for this case, because the movement is accelerating linearly from a non-0 initial value along the y-axis.)

`setInterval` can also be used (just cancel it when done, instead of starting a new timeout), but I find the `setTimeout` approach slightly easier to show conceptually. The difference is that `setInterval` will try to always run at time=iteration*timeout, which can - in degenerate cases - be noticeably more consistent than multiple setTimeout calls *or*, as pointed out Alnitak, it can stack/cascade harmfully.

Comment: actually `setInterval` timeouts can end up stacking, firing lots in immediate sequence.  With `setTimeout` that doesn't happen.

Comment: @Alnitak True; that's the flip side of the coin. I expanded the last sentence to acknowledge your point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the "shot" function every 500ms,

```
function shot() {
    document.getElementById('power').play();
    for (var i=140; i<400; i++)
    {  
        document.getElementById('shot').style.visibility='visible';
        imgShot.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) - 130 + 'px';  
        imgShot.style.top = parseInt(imgObj.style.top) - i + 'px';
    }
}

setInterval(shot,500);
```

Otherwise if you want to delay each iteration of the for loop, take look at this question that's almost a duplicate: [How to pause a FOR loop in Javascript in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497092/how-to-pause-a-for-loop-in-javascript-in-a-function)

Comment: I just want to freeze the loop for 500ms