# Wait until finish setTimeout

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to wait some time, execute one method and go on. Some one similar to:

```
setTimeout(()=> someMethod());
```

The problem is that the process goes on before the method is executed.

Could you help me?

Comment: Wait 5 seconds. setTimeout(()=> someMethod(), 5e3);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an equivalent Javascript or Jquery sleep function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277070/is-there-an-equivalent-javascript-or-jquery-sleep-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can wait on a promise as followed:

```js
const wait5s = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 5000)
  })
}

async function myFunc() {
  await wait5s()
  // Call you method here
  console.log('Hello World!')
}

myFunc()
```

Hope that answers your question.